# Extracting a 2D matrix from a 3D matrix in c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to code a function that, given an index as the input argument, extract the corresponding layer from a 3D matrix, returning a 2D matrix.

My default 3D matrix constructor looks something like this:

```
Matrice3D(unsigned int depth, unsigned int height, unsigned int width, const T &value) : _3D_matrix(0), _height(0), _width(0), _depth(0) { 

    try {
       _3D_matrix = new T[height * width * depth];
            for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                        _3D_matrix[y * width * depth + x * depth + z] = value; 
                    }
                }
            }
   }
    catch(...) {
        delete[] _3D_matrix;
        throw;
    }


    _height = height;
    _width = width;
    _depth = depth;

    }
```

(the `try/catch` is still a wip, I know it's not a thing to do).

So far, I've coded this:

```
void slice(int index) {

        try{
            _2D_matrix = new T[_height * _width]; 
        }catch(...){
            delete[] _2D_matrix;
            _height = 0;
            _width = 0;
            _depth = 0;
            throw;
        }

        _depth = 1;

        for (int k = 0; k< _depth; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j< _height; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i< _width; i++) {
                    _2D_matrix[j * _width + i] = 
                    _3D_matrix[j * _width * _depth + i * _depth + index];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I guess the logic behind the assignment done with the nested `for` cycles is right, but I don't really know how to return the new matrix. 
From the `main`, used to test the code, I'm calling

```
 std::cout << "--------TEST SLICE------------" << std::endl;
 Matrice3D<int> m1(3,3,3,17);
 std::cout << "Setter su (0,0,2,99)" << std::endl; 
 m1(0,0,2,91); //setting a value

 m1.slice(2);
 std::cout << "Matrix obtained from slicing the layer 2: " <<std::endl;
 std::cout << m1;
```

but I keep getting the first layer of the matrix, whatever index I choose for the input.

Comment: If you replace `T*` with `std::vector<T>`, you don't need all this try ... catch

Comment: Is `_2D_matrix` a data member of `Matrice3D` ?

Comment: @Caleth yes it is. Btw, I'm using `index` in the value assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class Matrice2D and return that in slice().

The reason why your get total garbage in your code is that you destroy the _depth of the 3D matrix. It's not even the first layer but really just garbage.

Comment: that seems to be a reasonable idea. do you think I should go for an inner class?

Comment: No. A 2D matrix is a thing all on it's own. Not a subclass of a 3D matrix. If you like you could make Matrix a vardiac template class able to have any number of dimensions. But that is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The only time `new` and `delete` should appear is in classes named `something_ptr`. You don't need raw pointers here, and you should be *returning* a `2DMatrix` from `slice`.

```
template <typename T>
class 2DMatrix;

template <typename T>
class 3DMatrix {
    std::vector<T> data;
    std::size_t height, width, depth;
public:
    3DMatrix(std::size_t height, std::size_t width, std::size_t depth, T value = {})
      : data(height * width * depth, value), 
        height(height), 
        width(width), 
        depth(depth) 
    {}

    2DMatrix<T> slice(std::size_t index) {
        2DMatrix<T> result(height, width);
        for (std::size_t i = index; i < data.size(); i += depth) {
            result.data[i / depth] = data[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    // other members
}

template <typename T>
class 2DMatrix {
    std::vector<T> data;
    std::size_t height, width;
    friend class 3DMatrix<T>;
public:
    2DMatrix(std::size_t height, std::size_t width, T value = {})
      : data(height * width, value), 
        height(height), 
        width(width) 
    {}

    // other members
}
```

Comment: I can't use `std::vector`, but no big deal I kept the raw pointers approach. Anyway, I get a "unknown type name `"2DMatrix"`" on the line where slice is called.

Comment: Oops, missed the `<T>` from it

Comment: if you have any chance to take a look at it, any help would be more than welcome (https://pastebin.com/uNDE1aA1)

Comment: Note: you can just `typedef T* iterator;` and `typedef const T* const_iterator` rather than all the boilerplate you currently have

Comment: Also given that you have defined sensible `operator()`s you can just use those. `result(i, j) = (*this)(i, j, index);`